# Await is not waiting for api post to finish, just happens simultaneously

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a problème which I can't seem to figure out.  I need this await call to happen only when it finishes one by one in the loop, but it seems like its just calling it twice in the same time quickly, which is not making the api post work correctly.

I've tried to use async, await, but the await doesn't seem to like it being in two loops. 
Has anyone got a better solution?

```
async pushToCreate() {
    const toCreate = this.json.toCreate

    let counter = 0

    // toCreate Sample = { en: [{}, {}] }, { fr: [{}, {}] }

    Object.keys(toCreate).forEach((item) => {
        toCreate[item].forEach((el) => {
            const lang = item
            const dataContent = el

            await this.wp.products().param('lang', lang).create({
                title: dataContent.dgn,
                fields:  dataContent,
                status: 'publish'
            }).then(function( response ) {
                counter++
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('error in create', err)
            })

            console.log('await finished')
        })
    })

    // should console log when above is finished
    console.log('END')
}
```

Comment: you are using lambda function inside the foreach loops, but they are synchronous, you need to make this function async

Comment: You might want to read [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/9374673).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to **await** for promises **forEach** will not help you. To make it work you should use:

   - **for/for..in/for..of** loops for the **sequential** processing and **await** for each **Promise** to become fulfilled on each iteration
   - **map** for the **parallel** processing which will return an array of promises and after that you can **await** for them to become fulfilled with **Promise.all()**
2. If you use **async/await** it looks more clear to use **try/catch** instead of **then/catch** chaining

Try this out if you need **sequential** processing:

```
...

  let lang;
  let dataContent;

  for (const item in toCreate) {
    lang = item;

    for (let i = 0; i < toCreate[lang].length; i++) {
      dataContent = toCreate[lang][i];

      try {
        await this.wp.products().param('lang', lang).create({
          title: dataContent.dgn,
          fields: dataContent,
          status: 'publish',
        });

        counter++;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error in create', err);
      }

      console.log('await finished');
    }
  }

...
```

or this if you need **parallel** processing:

```
...

  let lang;
  let dataContent;

  await Promise.all(
    Object.keys(toCreate).map(async item => {
      lang = item;

      await Promise.all(
        toCreate[lang].map(async el => {
          dataContent = el;

          try {
            await this.wp.products().param('lang', lang).create({
              title: dataContent.dgn,
              fields: dataContent,
              status: 'publish',
            });

            counter++;
          } catch (err) {
            console.log('error in create', err);
          }

          console.log('await finished');
        }),
      );
    }),
  );

...
```

Here is a good explanation of the **sequence** and **parallel** asynchronous calls handling using **async/await**: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a few issues with your code.

The first is that await only works when a function returns a promise. Functions that return promises initially return a value that indicates that a promise is pending. If the function you have on the right side of await does not return a promise, it will not wait.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

The second is that you are also using the .then() method, which triggers it's callback argument when the promise is fulfilled. I do not think you can use both await and .then().https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

If you want to have a similar format as the .then() .catch() pattern, you could use a try/catch block with the async/await.

```
async function f() {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('/example');
    let user = await response.json();
  } catch(err) {
    // catches errors both in fetch and response.json
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

https://javascript.info/async-await